# How to check if a decision tree satisfies an invariant?

Tags: model-checking, tla+

I know the decision tree and what the invariant is (if that's the right term). All the other definitions used (`UsingTor`, `UsingProxy`, etc. can be anything). How can I use TLA+ to check if every leaf of the decision tree satisfies the invariant?

I would know how to do this if the decision tree was a sequence of states: I'd check if it always ends up in a state satisfying this invariant. Not sure how to do this though.

```
Invariant ==
    /\ UsingTor => UsingProxy
    /\ UsingProxy => UsingTor
    /\ UsingProxy => UsingBlockingClient
    /\ UsingBlockingClient => UsingProxy
    /\ ToldToUseLocalBitcoinNode => ~ConfiguredToIgnoreLocalBtc
    /\ ConfiguredToIgnoreLocalBtc => ~ToldToUseLocalBitcoinNode
    /\ ToldToUseLocalBitcoinNode => ~UsingProxy
    /\ ~ToldToUseLocalBitcoinNode => DisableUseOfLocalBtcNode

DecisionTree ==
    \/ /\ UsingProxy
       /\ \/ /\ ConfiguredToIgnoreLocalBtc
             /\ UsingBlockingClient
          \/ /\ ~ConfiguredToIgnoreLocalBtc
             /\ UsingBlockingClient
             /\ UsingProxy
       /\ ~ToldToUseLocalBitcoinNode => DisableUseOfLocalBtcNode
    \/ /\ ~UsingProxy
       /\ ~UsingTor
       /\ ~UsingBlockingClient
```

Comment: You don't specify any temporal reasoning - in this case you should be able to just evaluate the expression `DecisionTree => Invariant` (i.e. the invariant follows from the tree).

Answer (score 1):

See this example that shows how to use ASSUME to assert some simple mathematical/constant formulas: https://github.com/tlaplus/Examples/blob/master/specifications/SpecifyingSystems/SimpleMath/SimpleMath.tla

Comment: Do you see a way to get more useful debugging without turning the decision tree into a state machine?

Comment: What do you consider more useful debugging?

Comment: Can you please inline the linked example inside your answer? S.O. frowns upon link-only answers, since the link can die anytime.